# Searching the Foursquare API with Python

Tags: python, http

I'd like some feedback on the readability, style, and potential problems or issues.

**foursquare.py**

```
import time

from api_keys import CLIENT_ID
from api_keys import CLIENT_SECRET
from api_keys import CATEGORY_ID

from business import Business
from business import make_request


def search(lat, lng, distance):
    """
    Searches the Foursquare API (Max Limit = 50)

    :param lat: Latitude of the request
    :param long: Longitude of the request
    :param distance: Distance to search (meters)
    :returns: List of retrieved venues
    """

    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=%s,%s&intent=browse&radius=%s&limit=50&categoryId=%s&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&v=%s' % (lat, lng, distance, CATEGORY_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    venue_list = []

    try:
        data = make_request(url)

        for item in data['response']['groups'][0]['items']:
            venue = item['venue']
            venue_list.append(Business(venue['name'],
                                       venue['location']['address'],
                                       venue['rating'],
                                       venue['ratingSignals'],
                                       venue['stats']['checkinsCount']))
    except Exception, e:
        print e

    return venue_list
```

**business.py**

```
import urllib2
import json


class Business:
    def __init__(self, name, address, rating, rating_count, checkin_count):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.rating = rating
        self.rating_count = rating_count
        self.checkin_count = checkin_count


def make_request(url):
    """
    Makes a new HTTP request to the given URL

    :param url: The URL to request
    :returns: JSON response
    """

    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    response.close()

    return data
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Named tuples**

`Business` is nothing short of a tuple where each attribute is named. Rather than going through the verbosity of writing everything out, you can just make it a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Business = namedtuple('Business', 'name address rating rating_count checkin_count')
```

**Managing resources**

For `make_request`, the preferred way to handle resources in Python is to use a context manager. For `urlopen`, we have [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
def make_request(url):
    with closing(urlopen(url)) as response:
        return json.loads(response.read())
```

Do you need to wrap it in `Request`? Not sure that gives you anything.

**String formatting**

Prefer the `format()` syntax to the `%` syntax. That is:

```
'Hello, {}'.format(name)
```

is better than:

```
'Hello, %s' % name
```

Comment: Good suggestion with the named tuples. Definitely improves the readability! I'll explore using the context manager as well. Is there a reason format is preferred? Just curious if it's personal preference or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @leerob See [string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/2069064)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to answer by Barry, I would like to state that your code has nice structure, good comments and reads easily. There are however a few minor points I would make:

- *Join the imports from the same module* – In general you shouldn't join *multiple `import`s* at the same line, but when getting things from the same module the recommendation is to join it like in: `from api_keys import CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CATEGORY_ID`
- *Extract the url pattern into a constant* – Most of the search url is constant, and could be moved to the top. Building the url has then a cleaner better focus on the changing parts:

  ```
  url = SEARCH_URL.format(lat, lng, distance,
                          CATEGORY_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                          time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
  ```